# Problems reading inputStream from a Uri and sending through an outputStream android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Good day, I am trying to send a file from an `SDCard` through an `OutputStream`. I intend to get the `URI` from the file name which I have and then use an `InputStream` to read the `URI` and convert to bytes in other to send. Currently the code is stuck in get `InputStream` (As commented below) and nothing happens.

Also, I don't know if I am using the `URI` correctly to get the actual path of the file to send.

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated because I have been stuck here for some time now. Thank you.

My code:

```
public void sendFile() {
    Log.d(TAG, "sending data");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
          .toString() + "/" + files.get(0);
    Log.d(TAG, "filepath is" + filePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);

    Log.d(TAG, "obtained input stream here in Activity");
    Log.d(TAG, "Uri here is" + uri);  // nothing happens after here, Basically stuck!!
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Log.d(TAG, "obtained input stream here in Activity");

        int buffersize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        AppServices.write(byteBuffer.toByteArray());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
```

or simply just use:

```
inputStream  = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

Comment: I tried both of them, but nothing seems to happen. can't even reach the logcat output after this line inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);.  not sure why?.

Comment: `File` is basically a reference to a file (even if it doen not yet exist).

Comment: You can try `(new File(filePath)).exists()` to check if file exists. Otherwise opening a stream on nonexistent file throws an exception. How do you handle exceptions?

Comment: Also, in second case you do not need to use `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`. You get input stream directly via `FileInputStream`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using 
`InputStream is = ctx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse("file://"+fileUri));`
But that won't cut it. It returns wierd byte results. I tried reading this way, but that diden't work either.

```
while (is.available() > 0) {
            outputStream.write(is.read(b));
}
```

**To make it work i do like this:**

> The **fileUri** param is a string like: "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/2013-05-07 15.53.47.jpg"

```
public static byte[] getImageAsBytes(String fileUri) throws IOException {
    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        return null;
    }
    //Get file stream
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileUri);
    //create output stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //create buffer
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    //Read the input to the bytestream
    int len = 0;
    while((len = is.read(b)) != -1){
        outputStream.write(b, 0, len);
    }
    is.close();
    //convert to bytearray
    final byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
    outputStream.close();
    return byteArray;
}
```